# AJAX request is not being submitted, but the Javascript function to it is called

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am entirely new to using AJAX, and I'm looking to generate some information dynamically, to calculate some dates, but ultimately that is not important.

I need to send the week and the year to the Javascript function which contains the AJAX code, which should then return information based upon what is found in the file it points to.

When I click a button, "Run Planner" it calls the following code. However, only the alert for "Accessed Function. Week = " + week + " Year = " + year" is called. The other alerts are not called implying they are not reached. Equally of course, the code on the page I'm requesting does not work either.

Could someone please point me in the right direction, or actively spot where I've went wrong?

Much appreciated:

```
<script>

function autoCalculatePlanner(week, year){

alert("Accessed Function. Week = " + week + " Year = " + year);
 xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert("State Ready");
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        alert("Document Submitted");
   }
     else{
         document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Error";
     }
    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax/auto_calculate_planner.php?week=" + week + "&year=" + year, true);;
    xhttp.send();
};


}



</script>
```

*Update*

The user "Don't Panic" provided an amended version of my code as follows:

```
function autoCalculatePlanner(week, year) {
alert("Accessed Function. Week = " + week + " Year = " + year);
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "ajax/auto_calculate_planner.php?week=" + week + "&year=" + year, true);;
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert("State Ready");
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        alert("Document Submitted");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Error";
    }
};
xhttp.send();
}
```

Which is incredibly helpful and at least evokes a response now. However, I am getting the "Error" message instead of having anything submitted. I've tried to do my own research, but again I cannot find how to get this resolved.

Could someone please provide additional information regarding where I may be going wrong?

Additional Information that may be required:

The file I'm trying to have processed via GET is found in a child folder named "ajax".
If the code from that file is suggested to be posted, I will do that also.

Comment: You need to do more debugging to narrow the problem down. Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Are there any errors? Look at the Network tab. Is the request sent? Does it look the way you expect? Do you get a response? Does it look the way you expect?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. You have shown the script, but no context for how the function is called. Are you using the onclick event of a link? That would cause the browser to navigate away before the response was recieved. You need to provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:php]. Why? There is no PHP in the question.

Comment: You have your `xhttp.open()` and `xhttp.send()` calls inside your `onreadystatechange` callback..... they need to be called outside that

Comment: @PatrickEvans — Good spot. The question show be closed because it was caused by a typo (`}` in the wrong place).

Comment: @Thielicious — That doesn't make it relevent to the PHP tag.

Comment: @Quentin As you can see, I provided context for how the code was submitted, on the click of a button. That would imply an onclick event and a button. However, for those who cannot pick up on such things, I will reaffirm this in an edit to the question. Equally PHP is tagged because as specified I am looking to receive information afterwards via PHP. Please do not continue to comment, if your contributions are not helpful.

Comment: @cmprogram — Your problem has nothing to do with PHP (or, if it does, there isn't enough information about the PHP in the question for anyone with PHP expertise to do anything useful), so the php tag is not aporpriate.

Comment: @cmprogram — There is no button in the code in your question. Mentioning a button is not the same as providing a [mcve]. There are significant differences between a submit button in a form (which could cause the problem you described) and a non-submit button.

Comment: If you have a new problem, don't edit it into the end of the existing question. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually performing the request until your `onreadystatechange` callback.  The state will never change if it the request does not happen.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
function autoCalculatePlanner(week, year) {
    alert("Accessed Function. Week = " + week + " Year = " + year);
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax/auto_calculate_planner.php?week=" + week + "&year=" + year, true);;
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert("State Ready");
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            alert("Document Submitted");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Error";
        }
    };
    xhttp.send();
}
```

[Reference docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange#Example).

Comment: @DontPanic This is fantastic, I'm definitely being pointed in the right direction. I'm not getting the "Error" message, so something is still wrong, but you definitely helped me with my question. Thank you! I'll accept this answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added a link to the Mozilla reference, and made a minor tweak to the code.

Comment: @cmprogram I guess you mean you are *now* getting the Error msg? If so, check your browser devtools, click the Network tab. You should see the AJAX request, click on it to see headers and response.  You should be able to see what went wrong there.

Comment: @DontPanic Yes that's what I meant. Fantastic, I'll try that and then pose a new question should I need further help. Thanks very much for helping and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

it's simply a paranthesis problem, you have to call xhttp.open and xhttp.send outside of xhttp.onreadystatechange, not inside

```js
function autoCalculatePlanner(week, year){
alert("Accessed Function. Week = " + week + " Year = " + year);
 xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert("State Ready");
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        alert("Document Submitted");
   }
     else{
         document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Error";
     }
    
};
xhttp.open("GET", "ajax/auto_calculate_planner.php?week=" + week + "&year=" + year, true);;
    xhttp.send();

}
```